# Ubuntu 16.04 on MacBook Pro 8.2 (2011) - Overheated CPU temperature

Tags: cpu, overheating, temperature, intel-cpu

Just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on sluggish Macbook pro and regretted why i didnt do it earlier. I have setup everything i wanted except couple of issues (touchpad is funky at times) but my majore concern is the hot CPU. runnign chrome browser for instance, takes it to 75 C and coping and installing stuff is taking it to above 90 degrees. any guess? what am i missing here?

PS: i am only using i915 driver